# Keyword tree construction using perl

Tags: perl, tree, keyword

I want to construct a keyword tree using perl programming. Here is the example, the keyword tree looks like this for the keywords "Apple,Apropos,Banana,Bandana,Orange".

[image]

This is the first time I am working on trees using perl. Moreover, I could not find enough information when I search for keyword trees in perl. I am not expecting the complete code. Just tell the starting point for doing the task. This would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google for ternary search tree its more memory efficient than trie but has more time complexity than trie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This data structure is commonly known as a trie, and looking for that yields [`Tree::Trie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tree::Trie). Maybe take a look at the source if you're looking for ideas for implementing one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash references for this issue like this:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $tree = { 
    root => {
        a => { 
            p => { 
                p => 'etc' , 
                r => 'etc'
            }, 
        },
        b => { 
            a => 'etc' 
        },
        o => { 
            r => 'etc' 
        },
    },
};

print Dumper($tree);
```

Or some CPAN modules: http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=tree