# Preserving the order of keywords found using Tree::Trie in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, tree

I am using the [`Tree::Trie`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tree%3a%3aTrie) module to build a keyword tree. I want to print the elements of an array in the order present in the original array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tree::Trie;

my @ar = ('foo', 'great','food', 'banana','apple', 'fish');

my ($trie) = new Tree::Trie;
$trie->add(@ar);
my @ms  = $trie->lookup('f');
print join(",", @ms);
```

Output is

```
fish,foo,food
```

Desired output

```
foo,food,fish
```

Can some one help me in this?

Comment: A trie is ordered lexicographically to begin with; could you give more information about what problem you're actually trying to solve? A trie may be the wrong thing altogether.

Comment: I am trying to construct a keyword tree and print in the inorder. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662352/keyword-tree-construction-using-perl

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use `Tree::Trie`'s `add_data` which would take your words with order data as follows:

```
'foo' => 0,'great' => 1,'food' => 2,'banana' => 3,'apple' => 4,'fish' => 5
```

and return the words with their associated data after a `lookup_data`.  That data can then be used to retain the original word order:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tree::Trie;

my @ar = qw( foo great food banana apple fish );

my $trie = Tree::Trie->new();
$trie->add_data( map { $ar[$_] => $_ } 0..$#ar );

my %ms = $trie->lookup_data('f');
my @ms = sort { $ms{$a} <=> $ms{$b} } keys(%ms);
print(join(',', @ms), "\n");
```

Output:

```
foo,food,fish
```

Comment: @ikegami - Thank you for the improvements.

Comment: You're welcome. You can even avoid the intermediary hash using `my $i = 1; my @ms = map $ar[$_], sort { $a <=> $b } grep ++$i % 2, $trie->lookup_data('f');`